# Draw (inverted) geometric circle in google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, geometry

I'm looking for a way to draw an inverted geometric (not geographical) circle in google maps api v3.

Essentially the goal is to dim the map except around a map object - as a way to make the map object stand out. To do this, I have employed an inverted overlay and have a method to create the circle "hole" in my "shadow-overlay".

However the method I've employed to get the lat/lng coordinates to generate this circle is adjusted to the Mercator projection and is not a consistent size or shape because it is relative to it's position from the equator. The method needs to create a circle (without using google's circle object - or using it with a way to extract it's path) that will calculate the lat/lng points from a center, based on a radius field that doesn't take the Mercator projection into account - such that it will display a perfect circle anywhere it is drawn on the map.

It shouldnt be hard, but I'm struggling to convert this function to NOT apply the Mercator projection into the result:

```
function getCircleCoords(point, radius) {
  var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians
  var points = 90;
  var circleLatLngs = new Array();
  var circleLat = radius * 0.621371192 * 0.014483;
  var circleLng = circleLat / Math.cos( point.lat() * d2r);
  for (var i = 0; i < points+1; i++) { 
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points / 2)); 
    var vertexLat =  point.lat() + (circleLat * Math.sin(theta)); 
    var vertexLng =  point.lng() + (circleLng * Math.cos(theta));

    var vertexLat =  point.lat() + (circleLat * (theta)); 
    var vertexLng =  point.lng() + (circleLng * (theta));

    var vertextLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(vertexLat, vertexLng);
    circleLatLngs.push( vertextLatLng );
  }
  return circleLatLngs;
}
```

This would then get called like:

```
feature = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [[my_shadow_layer_path],[getCircleCoords(latLng_, 800)] ],
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    map: map_
  });
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To use a Polygon, you need to calculate the circle coordinates in pixel (world) coordinates translate them to geographic coordinates using [fromPointToLatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection) to get the appropriate coordinates for the circle.  Or use an overlay of the correct size and handle zoom changes yourself.

Comment: Right do you know how to go about calculating the circle coordinates in pixel-format?

Comment: It is just a [normal circle](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/equation-of-a-circle.php).

Comment: I can't use a normal circle because I need to add the circle's path to a Polygon so I can invert the circle within it.

Comment: You need to calculate the "normal circle" in pixel coordinates.  Convert those to lat/lng coordinates, then add them to the Polygon.  Recalculate when the zoom level changes.

Comment: I don't know how to create a "normal circle" in pixel coordinates. Do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library https://github.com/raihan2006i/google-map-inverted-circle. which works on Google Map V3. See below for example code blocks

```
var iCircle;
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('gMap');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    iCircle = new InvertedCircle({
        center: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        radius: 5000, // 5 km
        editable: true,
        stroke_weight: 5,
        fill_opacity: 0.5,
        fill_color: "#ff0000"
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```